# How to spend UTXO in corda

Tags: corda

I learned how to create output state by corda.
However, I can't find documentation about how to consume those created outputs.

How can I specify outputs I want to consume as inputs in Flow code?

Answer (score 1):

Usually it's like this:

1. Your state is a `LinearState` that has some `UUID` attribute as its `linearId`.
2. The flow that wants to consume that state has a constructor that takes as an input parameter that `linearId`.
3. Inside the flow you query the vault of the node to get that state by its `linearId`; the query returns a `StateAndRef` of your state.
4. You add that `StateAndRef` as an input to your transaction.
5. Let's say you're trying to update that state, so you add to the transaction an output; that output has the same value for `linearId`; but you can modify any other attribute. So this way you mimic an update, because states in Corda are final; so to update one, you consume it, then you create an output that has the same `linearId` but different values for the remaining attributes. This allows you to track the history of that state by its `linearId`.
6. [This example](https://github.com/corda/samples-java/blob/732187bac8ce572a351b78a021bf2e59f7a5b51f/Advanced/negotiation-cordapp/workflows/src/main/java/negotiation/flows/ModificationFlow.java#L35-L73) shows the above steps, you'll see that the flow constructor takes the Id of the proposal, queries the vault for that proposal; then updates its amount by creating a new proposal with the same Id but different amount.